# Mass percentage of water in hydrate?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

1.034 g of a metal sulfate hydrate was heated to a high enough temperature to remove all the water of hydration. The mass of the anhydrous salt left behind was found to be 0.956 g. What is the mass percentage of water in the hydrate?

I did $1.034-0.956=0.078$ grams of water

Then I did $\frac{0.078}{1.034}$= about $7.5$%

Is this correct?

Comment: Was not calculation of percentage taught in a basic/elementary school ? It is a real fundamental knowledge for anyvody who deals with chemistry. Rather a shame to ask.....

Comment: @Poutnik but is my interpretation of the question correct. Im not asking if the algebra is correct.

Comment: Lack of effort..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chemistry calculation problems often disappear, if stripped down from the "dark chemistry magic".

It is really just percentage calculation, especially if everything has been commented explicitly like here.

Yes, it is correct.